# If I have two Datasets in SSRS which are from stored procedures, can I pass data between them?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportserver

I have an SSRS report which creates a multi-page report of Customer IDs and their associated batch codes.

- We usually send the report to our client every few weeks, but the report may be run on any day of the week/month.
- The report must only contain Customer IDs which have not already been sent.

I achieve this by logging the Customer IDs that have been sent in a "Sent" table, then left joining on that to exclude IDs that have already been sent.

Page 1 comes from one stored procedure, Page 2 comes from another.

Stored Proc 1 / Page 1 is a select of customer accounts, including batch code, which have not already been selected, then the stored proc logs those details to the sent table:

```
--Select new records for report into temp table
     SELECT a.CustomerID,
            a.BatchCode
       INTO #CustomersToSend
       FROM dbo.CustomerBatches a
  LEFT JOIN dbo.Sent b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
      WHERE b.SentDate IS NULL

--Insert these records into the sent table
INSERT INTO dbo.Sent
     SELECT CustomerID,
            GETDATE() AS SentDate
       FROM #CustomersToSend

--Select the temp table to produce the report output
     SELECT * 
       FROM #CustomersToSend
```

Stored Proc 2 needs to be a summary of batch codes contained in Page 1:

```
--Batch Summary
     SELECT BatchCode,
            COUNT(*) AS TotalCustomers
       FROM dbo.CustomerBatches
   GROUP BY BatchCode
```

I need to fiter this query in the same way as I filtered the first one, excluding any CustomerIDs that have already been sent.

My problem is I don't know how SSRS handles this type of report.

If it runs stored proc 1, waits for it to finish, then runs stored proc 2, then fine, I can use the SentDate in dbo.Sent to filter on CustomerIDs sent in the last few seconds.

If it runs both stored proc 1 and 2 at the same time, then I could possibly use the same logic as Stored Proc 1, a left join onto dbo.Sent in order to exclude sent CustomerIDs. I'm not sure what would happen if stored proc 2 was running at the very moment that stored proc 1 was trying to write to dbo.Sent however...

Ideally, I would have it run stored proc 2 first, wait for it to finish, then run stored proc 1. But my output from stored proc 1 *must* be page 1 of the report. I figure if it does run them in serial rather than in parallel, then it would go in page order?

Any help / insight would be appreciated.

Comment: You could build the `Sent` table with two separate datetime columns: `Page1SentDate` and `Page2SentDate`...

Comment: Good idea :) I ran some tests and it does look like SSRS is running both stored procs at the exact same time. I think I can get away with just one sent date, since the two queries will be identical up until the point they join on dbo.sent... Having two dates in there would make it difficult to know if my records would be there before trying to update the date in the second proc...

Comment: You could use a `MERGE` instead of `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. I wonder what will happen when both procedures will fill the `Sent` table at the same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use only one dataset. You can re-use your first dataset in a summary table on the second page, grouping the records in that table by `BatchCode` and letting SSRS do the counting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I did some digging, and SSRS is triggering both stored procedures at exactly the same time.

This is good and bad. Bad, because I can't pass any data from one proc to the other during the report run, but good because it means so long as my two queries are identical at the beginning, they should finish building the temp table at the exact same time.

So my stored proc 1 remains the same, but my stored proc 2 is now this:

```
--Select new records for report into temp table
   SELECT a.CustomerID,
          a.BatchCode
     INTO #CustomersToSend2
     FROM dbo.CustomerBatches a
LEFT JOIN dbo.Sent b ON a.CustomerID = b.CustomerID
    WHERE b.SentDate IS NULL

--Batch Summary
   SELECT BatchCode,
          COUNT(*) AS TotalCustomers
     FROM #CustomersToSend2
 GROUP BY BatchCode
```

Since the two queries run in parallel, they finish building the temp table at the beginning right at the same moment (before query 1 has a chance to start adding rows to dbo.sent) so they both have the exact same Data in their respective temp tables.

I guess the only risk is that if there was some issue preventing Query 2 starting that didn't prevent Query 1 starting, I might get no results in my summary, but I think it should be fine.

Comment: In your Data Source's Properties, there's a check box for `Use Single Transaction`. If you check that box, the datasets that use the Data Source will run one at a time.